# SwiftUI draggable view containing scrollable List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have built a bottom sheet kind of view like in the iOS Music App, it contains some static data followed by a `List` with dynamic content. I am using `DragGesture` on the view to let the user drag the view up or down, which works fine. But with having a `List` inside of that view, the `List` catches the vertical scroll and just bounces the list. My goal would be to somehow cancel what the `List`'s scrolling behaviour does (bouncing) and let the parent `DragGesture` handle the scrolling, which would make the whole view move down.

For better understanding, I'm attaching a screenshot with some markup:
[image]

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any ideas on this?